# No errors in debug mode in visual c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I created a program with **visual studio 2010** express c# edition, and when I run the program in the editor it works good, but when I start the built .exe file. It throws **out of memory error** messages to me.

I know that the errors occurred also in debug and normal mode, but it doesn't throw any exception while debugging. How can I monitor these errors in the debug mode? I'm working with the webbrowser control.

Comment: Could you provide some more information, such as the text of the error you're seeing, or some more specific details as to the problem you are having? How are you running the built file? What kind of project is it?

Comment: You're more likely to get a response if you post what sort of exceptions you're getting, example code, even showing us where it falls over in the example code? Also, what solution platform you're targetting (e.g. x68, x64, Any CPU)?

Comment: Seriously? "it throws error messages to me" with no info about what the errors are or what your code does, no posted code, nothing? And you expect us to help you **how**,exactly. When you type the word "error" or "exception", the very next thing you should type should be the **exact** error or exception message you received, including any error codes or memory addresses. Please remember that we can't see your screen or read your mind from here, and so we have *absolutely* no information except what you give us in your question. Please edit your post to provide more info (some code would help).

Comment: The error window displays an out of memory message, but no error in visual studio (simply continuing, without any sign of error). Is it maybe due to the webbrowser control?

Comment: First of all, which errors are thrown?

Answer (score 4):

Goto Debug -> Exceptions and check the checkbox to break when a CLR exception is thrown.

If you're debugging from within Visual Studio the above will be sufficient. If however, you're running the exe from outside of visual studio you first need to attach to the process:

- Debug -> Attach to process
- Choose YourProgram.exe from list
- Click attach